# Removing binary symbol from text file

Tags: text, awk, sed

I'm using dos2unix command to convert a text file to unix format, but I'm getting this message for several files:

```
dos2unix: Binary symbol found at line 6115
dos2unix: Skipping binary file w1.txt
```

and when I open the text file in notepad++, I see the following:

[image]

How do I remove these binary symbols from the text file? Is there any command I could use?

Comment: try `perl -p -e 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' inputfile` , this will remove non-ascii chars. Not sure if this will work on your file, although worth trying.

Comment: Maybe those are just multibyte characters? Have you checked the encoding of the file?

Comment: I don't think it is wise to remove this binary chars; what you need to do is probably to convert these chars into the correct encoding. **dos2unix** have a lot of options for doing that. Try to know the encoding of your original file and also the encoding to which you try to migrate in notepad++. There are examples here: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/dos2unix.htm

Comment: What does `file` report as the encoding? Can you dump a few lines of `hexdump -C` output? Lines 6130-6136 would be nice as `PUI` seems like æ (wrt 6131) and `SSA` like å.

Comment: If you rename [`Holbæk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holb%C3%A6k) to `Holbk` it's not going to be the same city.

Comment: I personally use `todos`/`fromdos` or just change NL mode in `vim` if editing, but... with `dos2unix 7.4.0`, you seem to have `-f` option: *"force conversion of binary files"* which may be applicable in your case? Don't worry you think it's binary... try to replace CRLF sequence with LF as you see them.

Comment: The file is UTF-8 encoded. It was a file from a unix server but the strange thing is that it was never converted to LF and when I retrieved it from the server, it was already represented as a windows CRLF.

Answer (score 0):

These are private use only characters. [More Info](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html)

If you are using dos2unix for removing **carriage return** char, you can try the below alternative.

```
sed -i -e 's/\r//g' file
```